# Fastest way to write many xlsx files from a single text file in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have to periodically convert a running log/text file (300K+ lines, 20MB+) into many different xlsx files (approx. 2K+ files of varying length). At the same time, I'm creating a directory tree based on data within the file.

The idea is to create a script that can be re-run as often as required. It only takes me 6-7 seconds to read the entire file for all the information I need, but it currently takes about 2 minutes to generate all the xlsx files the first time around. I'm only a couple of weeks into python, so I'm not sure if this is reasonable or not.

I'm using openpyxl (on Windows 7) because of its sheet protection capabilities, but I'm not sure if there's a faster process that can do the same thing. Any replacement process would need to have sheet protection and column width adjustment capabilities.

I've tried the "write_only" mode, but I didn't notice a discernible difference in speed. Removing cell protection didn't seem to have an impact, either.

```
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    close_prev_file = False
    # Turn off additional regex lookups until needed (speeds up read process)
    read_body = False
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        # Header handling
        if re.search(<large regex pattern>,line,re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
            # Activate dormant regex lookups below (slows down read process)
            read_body = True
            # If header information is found, finish writing any previous files and start a new one
            if close_prev_file is True:
                path = <pattern from concatenated variable results>
                new_file = path + <variable results> + ".xlsx"
                # If the new_file doesn't already exist, create it
                if os.path.exists(new_file) is False:
                    distutils.dir_util.mkpath(path)
                    print("Generating Excel file: " + new_file)
                    wb.save(new_file)
            close_prev_file = True
            wb = Workbook()
            ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")
            <apply sheet protection>
        # Body text handling
        elif read_body is True:
            # Read current line, decide how to format the output
            < if/then code>
                # Format xample: pull data from the line, split into two columns
                #ws.cell(row=row, column=1, value=re.sub("<pattern>","",line,0,re.IGNORECASE))
                #ws.cell(row=row, column=2, value=re.search("<pattern>","",line,0,re.IGNORECASE).group(0))
            <build variables from regex searches of subsequent lines>
            # If the intended file already exists, skip further regex searches and resume looking for header info
            if <all variables established>:
                path = <pattern from concatenated variable results>
                new_file = path + <variable results> + ".xlsx"
                if os.path.exists(new_file) is True:
                    <turn off reading, reset variables>
                    close_prev_file = False
                    read_body = False
```

Comment: openpyxl in write-only mode, with lxml installed, is very fast at creating Excel files. As suggested below you can probably parallelise the file creation as well.

Comment: @CharlieClark I did the 'pip install lxml', but that didn't improve the speed at all. I've tried other installation methods, but I'm not sure how my script is supposed to interact with it to cause a speed increase. The write_only mode is only 10 seconds faster than the normal mode, which isn't significant against the 2+ minutes of normal script execution. Thoughts?

Comment: This tells us that openpyxl isn't really the bottleneck. You can now start looking at ways to paralellise the process which will require you to split the code up into functions. You might also want to create the relevant regexes outside the loops.

Comment: I dug a little deeper and it turned out I was missing some of the dependencies for lxml. I saw the dependencies in the documentation, but I wasn't sure if they were part of the default python installation or if I'd have to actively hunt them out, and figured the install process would complain if the dependencies weren't there. Apparently I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You could try offloading the IO operation of writing xlsx files on threads.
Pythons threading module does not preform operations in parallel because of the GIL (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

However performance can increase when interleaving IO and non IO operations in different threads.

Here I generate 100 random numpy arrays as well as saving them to disk with np.savetxt. Significant performance is gained from offloading IO on threads.

```
%%time
count = 0
while count < 100:

    array = np.random.randint(1, size=(200, 600))

    np.savetxt(str(uuid.uuid1(count)), array)

    count += 1
```

> CPU times: user 5.24 s, sys: 307 ms, total: 5.55 s
>
> Wall time: 28.9 s

```
%%time
thread_list = []
count = 0
while count < 100:

    if threading.active_count() > 8:
        continue

    array = np.random.randint(1, size=(200, 600))

    thread = threading.Thread(target=np.savetxt,
                              args=[str(uuid.uuid1(count)), array])

    thread_list.append(thread)
    thread.start()

    count += 1

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
```

> CPU times: user 18 s, sys: 660 ms, total: 18.6 s
>
> Wall time: 18.5 s

You could try offloading the call to wb.save(new_file) on separate threads. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
import threading
if threading.active_count() > 8: # Choose a number suitable for your pc.
    [thread.join() for thread in thread_list]

else:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=wb.save,
                              args=[new_file])

    thread_list.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

Of cause you need to define "thread_list = []" somewhere outside your main loop etc. Also join remaining threads before exit.

Edit: dont forget to import the threading lib:)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm hitting other bottlenecks now, but this is definitely good to know!